# On what basis GitHub Advisory filter vulnerabilities for different package managers?

Tags: github, security, twitter-bootstrap-3, npm-vulnerabilities

I am trying to comprehend how GitHub Advisory filters vulnerabilities, particularly in the context of Bootstrap 3.3.7. In the National Vulnerability Database (NVD), the following vulnerabilities are reported for Bootstrap 3.3.7:

CVE-2019-8331
CVE-2018-20677
CVE-2018-20676
CVE-2016-10735
CVE-2018-14042
CVE-2018-14040
However, when I look at GitHub Advisory, these vulnerabilities are segregated based on the package manager. For instance, CVE-2019-8331 is reported on NuGet, RubyGems, and npm, but not other vulnerabilities. Similarly, other vulnerabilities are reported only on npm and not on other package managers.

Since all these package managers are presumably building from the same codebase of Bootstrap, I'm curious about the rationale behind GitHub Advisory's filtration of vulnerabilities. Why are certain vulnerabilities reported only for specific package managers and not uniformly across all?

I would appreciate any insights or explanations regarding this discrepancy in the GitHub Advisory Database. Thank you!